# JavaFX How to Center Multiple Components side by side

Tags: java, javafx, alignment, javafx-8, gridpane

I have 2 components: `Label` & `Button`. I want to put them side by side & align them together in CENTER. But I failed to do so, as they are still aligned LEFT but not CENTER.

[image]

My code as below:

```
Label sloganLbl = new Label("With cost as low as $1.99, you can own a fraction share of U.S. stock. No account yet?");
sloganLbl.getStyleClass().add("blue-small-font");


Button signUpBtn = new Button("Open account now");
signUpBtn.getStyleClass().add("green-btn-small-font");

GridPane topGrid = new GridPane();

topGrid.setHgap(20);
topGrid.add(sloganLbl, 0, 0);
topGrid.add(signUpBtn, 1, 0);
topGrid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

GridPane.setHalignment(sloganLbl, HPos.RIGHT);
GridPane.setHalignment(signUpBtn, HPos.LEFT);

BorderPane topBorder = new BorderPane();
topBorder.setPadding(new Insets(15, 10, 15, 10));
topBorder.setCenter(topGrid);

topBorder.getStyleClass().add("blue-small-font");
topGrid.getStyleClass().add("blue-small-font");

borderPane.setTop(topBorder);
```

The problem is `topBorder.setCenter(topGrid);` is not able to center the content in center. Seems `topGrid` is taking up full width, not just total width of it's 2 columns.

How can I achieve the center alignment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the `GridPane` with a gap filler column on the left and on the right.

```
ColumnConstraints leftFiller = new ColumnConstraints();
leftFiller.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS); // Fills the space left on the left side
ColumnConstraints rightFiller = new ColumnConstraints();
rightFiller.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS); // Fills the space left on the right side
topGrid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftFiller, new ColumnConstraints(), 
    new ColumnConstraints(), rightFiller);

topGrid.add(sloganLbl, 1, 0);
topGrid.add(signUpBtn, 2, 0);
```

This snippet will create a `GridPane` with 4 columns. The first and the last is growing when the `GridPane` becomes resized, the 2 inner columns hold the `Label` and the `Button`.

Please notice that the `Label` and the `Button` are now placed into the second and third column.

Comment: Very cool @DVarga, your code fixed my problem. Thanks a bunch!